# compare two files and pass it to another file shell bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have to create a script which reads information out of a file (csv) and compares with the  file2 (csv) if its available. The file2 has aswell a line which tells me a price.

When ever its matches it should put the output into a third file.

I use the cut command to check was exist (`cut -f1 -d ";" file1.csv`) but how to I compare it then with the second file?

Update:
Well file one has information about: Software name;Version;Vendor

File 2: has information about: Software;Price;license time

File 3: Should be the result.

The Point is to find out how many license are used and how much is it costing the department. how many license, Price, Coast total are using the clients.

Comment: Please show examples of the input files and the output you're trying to get.

Comment: down vote accept
 

Thank you for your answers!

Well file one has information about: Software name;Version;Vendor

File 2 has information about: Software;Price;license time

File 3:

Should be the result.

The Point is to find out how many license are used and how much is it costing the department. how many license, Price, Coast total are using the clients.

Comment: Formatting is lost in comments, please update your question so you can show the files with their formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use diff command to compare two fiels

e.g.
diff file1.csv file2.csv

Answer (score 0):

Use awk to read the second file into an array.  Then iterate through the first file and print the desired information whenever the associated key is in the array.  Since you haven't given enough detail to provide an accurate answer, the following is merely a guess.  It assumes that the price is in the second column, and the key is in the first.  If an item is repeated in the 2nd file, the price reported will be the second value given.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{keys[$1]=$2; next} 
    $1 in keys { print $1, keys[$1] }' FS=\; file2.csv file1.csv
```